# Get SelectedItem from Combobox

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jcombobox

Like this i can output the selected value from the ComboBox..

```
public static String selectedString(ItemSelectable is) {
    Object selected[] = is.getSelectedObjects();
    return ((selected.length == 0) ? "null" : (String)selected[0]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add ActionListener
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                ItemSelectable is = (ItemSelectable)actionEvent.getSource();
                String name=selectedString(is);
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        };

        // Add Actionlistener to ComboBox kundeAuswahl
        kundeAuswahl.addActionListener(actionListener);

       // i wanna have the value of name for use here:
       // String test[] = getChildAsArray("kunde","projekt",name);
}
```

But i would like to get the Value **name** out of this function, normally i use return, but this gives me an error. How do i have to do this, then?

Comment: like this isn't proper way, ending in most cases with quite correct suggestion, but complicated wrong concept more and more, to try to avoiding that, move any GUI and its Listener to the public methods or voids, then all anwers here couldn't correct or change that, for (real and) better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that selecting something in a `ComboBox` is an *event*: the event handler is executed when the event occurs. However, the last lines of your example are executed *when the combobox is created*.

Therefore, the `name` is not available at that time. However, you can call any function you like from the event handler:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            ItemSelectable is = (ItemSelectable)actionEvent.getSource();
            String name=selectedString(is);

            doSomethingWithName(name);
        }
    };

    // Add Actionlistener to ComboBox kundeAuswahl
    kundeAuswahl.addActionListener(actionListener);
}

public static void doSomethingWithName(String name) {
    String test[] = getChildAsArray("kunde","projekt",name);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I wanna use the name as a param to call another function -> i edited code to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Use a class variable.

```
  class Abc{


   String itemname

   ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            ItemSelectable is = (ItemSelectable)actionEvent.getSource();
            String name=selectedString(is);
            itemname=name;
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
      // use itemname in class

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what you are trying to achieve but seems like both a class member variable and/or calling a class method from your anonymous class would do the trick.

Also you cannot return a String on `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)` since the method's return type is void.